# Why is Chrome not showing pictures from an S3 bucket?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, amazon-s3

In my site, when using Firefox I can see this image `http://live.user.data.s3.amazonaws.com/user/photo/7583/thumb_profile_JZ_Blue_shirt_cropped_3_Jan_2013_color_adj.jpg`

However, when trying to open that URL in Chrome nothing happens - why could that be?

Comment: If at all, this is an Amazon S3 issue, there is no EC2 involved (at least concerning how you phrased your question) - that said, I can see the image just fine in both Firefox and Chrome, have you tried to refresh your browser cache and/or restart Chrome?

Comment: yes. and it loads forever @SteffenOpel